# query inside function returns NULL, query returns a value

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, datetime-format

Disclaimer: I am new to PostgreSQL, and even newer to functions in plpgSQL. I've read the documentation but I am stumped.

Anyway, I have this function, to pick a charge band out of a table for asterisk CDR rating:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getBand(
    callDateTime varchar
) RETURNS varchar AS $$
/* Select correct charging band */
DECLARE
    callTime varchar;
    callDay varchar;
    theBand varchar;
BEGIN
    /* Find the time and the day of the call */
    callTime := to_char(to_timestamp(callDateTime,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI:SS');
    callDay := to_char(to_timestamp(callDateTime,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'Day');
    theBand := band 
    FROM bands 
    WHERE day = callDay 
    AND start < callTime 
    AND finish > callTime 
    LIMIT 1;
    RETURN theBand;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

The input string is lifted from the asterisk CDR table, and is in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'.

The bands table is in the format

```
day | band | start | finish
============================
```

Where 'day' is the name of a weekday, band is the charge band for a call ("Peak", "Off Peak", "Weekend") and start and finish are the start and finish times for that charge band.

When I run

```
SELECT getBand('2013-05-03 11:30:00');
```

I get a NULL result.

When I run

```
SELECT band FROM bands
WHERE day = 'Friday' AND start < '11:30:00' and finish > '11:30:00' LIMIT 1;
```

I get the correct answer (for my data): 'Peak'

I'm confused. Anyone want to tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Because `to_char(..., 'Day')` returns a string that has space-padding at the end. Wrap the expression assigned to `callDay` in `trim()`:

```
callDay := trim(to_char(to_timestamp(callDateTime,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'Day'));
```

(I finally found this by adding `raise info 'calltime="%", callday="%"', calltime, callday` although I went down quite a few dead ends first)

(This was rather confusing: `theBand := band FROM bands ...` - it would be more usual to write `SELECT band INTO theBand FROM bands ...`)

Comment: I did what you suggested and it didn't work. Then I noticed that I had the '<' and '>' signs in the wrong places... no rows were getting picked up. I knew it was my own stupidity at play, but I didn't think it would be that fundamental...

Comment: You may be interested in the `FM` modifier.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_band(call_ts timestamp)
  RETURNS text AS
$func$
   SELECT band 
   FROM   bands 
   WHERE  day = to_char(call_ts,'FMDay')
   AND    start <= call_ts::time
   AND    finish > call_ts::time
   ORDER  BY start 
   LIMIT  1
$func$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

- The [**template pattern**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE) `'Day'` of `to_char()` gives you, I quote:

  > full capitalized day name (blank-padded to 9 chars)

  To remove the blank padding there is a **[template pattern modifier](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIMEMOD-TABLE)**: `FM`. So make that: **`'FMDay'`**. No need for `trim()`.
- `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS` is the standard ISO 8601 format, which works with *any* locale. There is no good reason to use a `varchar`, make it a **`timestamp`** to begin with. Yes, the data type for a point in time is called timestamp in Postgres (not `datetime`). That's why I chose the parameter name `call_ts` for it.
- Don't use unquoted, **mixed-case identifiers**. Ever. It just leads to confusion. They are all cast to lower case. That's the next reason I chose `call_ts`.
- Don't use `to_char()` to get a `time` from a `timestamp`. Just **cast**. Much simpler and faster. **`call_ts::time`**
- You don't need **plpgsql** for this simple query at all, make it a plain **SQL** function or just use the query.
- In plpgsql it's best to let SQL commands to the work, instead of lots of little **assignments** (which are comparatively expensive). Even if I had not converted it to `LANGUAGE sql`, I would use this single compact query.
- `LIMIT 1` without **`ORDER BY`** gives you an *arbitrary* result that can change at any time. If you care at all which row you get or if you want it to be stable at least, you have add `ORDER BY`!
- It's a dubious practice to have a time interval with  `start < x AND finish > x`. Usually you want to include the lower bound, so I used **`<=`**.
- Did you consider [**time zones**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)?
- I would save an integer for the weekday instead of the name of the day.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that either query is working, if day contains '2013-05-03' rather than 'Friday'... There's no issue with your SQL, but there certainly seems to be one with your schema.

Postgres has a range type, and that's probably what you should be using here:

```
create table bands (
  id serial primary key,
  name varchar,
  playing tsrange
);

insert into bands (name, playing) values ('test', '[2013-05-03 11:00:00, 2013-05-03 12:00:00]');

select name from bands where playing @> '2013-05-03 11:30:00'::timestamp;

create or replace function getBand(_datetime timestamp) returns varchar as $$
  select name from bands where playing @> _datetime limit 1;
$$ language sql;

select getBand('2013-05-03 11:30:00');
```

Comment: Please read the question more carefully before responding. The input string is in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', as it comes from the Asterisk CDR table. The "bands" table is a list of charge bands for calls, used to determine when "peak", "off peak" and "weekend" call tariffs are active. The table has the format `'band', 'day', 'start','end'`. An example of a valid row would be `'Monday','Peak','08:00:00','18:00:00'`.